# How to set x-axis label for every y-value in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I want to set a label in the x-axis for every y-value I have in my LineChart. I want to obtain this result:

[image: a LineChart with labels on the x-axis for every point]

Can someone help me in finding the correct way of doing this in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for *granularity* - see [the wiki page for the axis](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis) and the [javadoc](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.2/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/AxisBase.html).

Calling like this:

```
 mChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(0.3f);
 mChart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled(true);
```

will ensure that `0.3` is the minimum interval on the axis when you are zoomed in. Apart from that you may have to tweak the the scale of the x-axis by calling:

```
mChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinValue(10.01f); //experiment with these values
mChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaxValue(10.14f);
mChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(5);
```